# SELECT fields from two tables through variable

Tags: php, select, multiple-tables

I'm trying to obtain this question several hours with no result. Hope you could help me!!
Let me explain:
My tables:
table1: pm_proveedores
fields: prov_ID, prov_nif, prov_nombre, prov_email
Table 2: pm_productos
fields: prod_ID, prov_prod_nif, prod_fechafactura, prod_numerofactura

I display in one page (prod_search.php):

```
$query="select * from pm_productos where prod_nombreproducto like '%$search%' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result=mysql_query($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<tr>
   <td>",$row[1],"</td>
   <td>",date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row[2])),"
   <td><a href='fact_view.php?roll=".$row[3]."'>".$row[3]."</a></td>
   <td>",$row[4],"</td> etc, etc....
```

In the other page (prod_view.php) I get "$roll" and displays all rows with this same "$roll":

```
<? $roll=$_GET["roll"];?>
$query="SELECT * FROM pm_productos where prod_numerofactura='$roll'";

$result=mysql_query($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<tr>
 <td>",$row[1],"</td>
 <td>",date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row[2])),"</td>
     <td>",$row[3],"</td>
   <td>",$row[4],"</td> etc,etc....
```

My question is: How to display in page 2, the field prov_nombre from table 1, where table2.prov_prod_nif = table1.prov_nif?
(both fields "table2.prov_prod_nif" and "table1.prov_nif" contain the same number) 
Thank you in advance for your great help!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the inner join command.

```
$query = "SELECT pm_productos.*, pp.prov_nombre FROM pm_productos INNER JOIN pm_proveedores pp ON pp.prov_nif = pm_productos.prov_prod_nif WHERE prod_nombreproducto like '%$search%' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

pm_productos.* = pick all columns from 2nd table.

pp.prov_nombre = pick column prov_nombre from pm_proveedores table, (named as pp in 'pm_proveedores pp' after JOIN statement)

Comment: If I understand, this answer assumes that a search has been done?
But, what about if I a search is not carried out, I mean, displaying all records and clicking an a href link in the table of this "search" page?
Thanks!!!